# Close the modal once user click on Finish button in docusign

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, docusignapi

I am displaying sign URL of docusign in iframe.

Now once user click on FINISH then I want to close that modal iframe.

Right now it is redirecting to redirect url in iframe.. check below screenshot so once user click on FINISH then need to close this modal.

I am using Angular and .net core API. -- From API response I am getting that signing URL from which user can sign pdf.

[image]

Comment: Is your problem solved ? If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

> Re: how an application can start a DocuSign signing ceremony in an iFrame (embedded signing, also known as captive signing) and then later cleanly close the iFrame?

first issue, iFrames are not recommended for signing ceremonies since IDV does not support iFrames.

Alternatives:

1. Open a new tab (and then later close it)
2. Replace the application with the signing ceremony and then later restart it

In case 1, a pattern is to have the signing ceremony open a webpage after the signing ceremony is complete. That webpage then sends a message to the application. The application then closes the signing ceremony tab. (This pattern can also be used with iFrames. But remember, iFrames are not recommended.)

A [live example](https://codepen.io/docusign/full/MWXPKJY) that demonstrates this technique. See the [source](https://github.com/docusign/docusign.github.io/blob/master/jsfiddleDsResponse.html) for the page DocuSign redirects to. It uses [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to notify the parent window to close the tab.

```
const dsReturnUrl = "https://docusign.github.io/jsfiddleDsResponse.html";

    async function embeddedSigningCeremony({ envelopeId, signer }) {
        const req = {
            returnUrl: dsReturnUrl,
            authenticationMethod: "None",
            clientUserId: signer.clientUserId,
            email: signer.email,
            userName: signer.name
        };

        // Make the API call
        const apiMethod = `/accounts/${accountId}/envelopes/${envelopeId}/views/recipient`;
        const httpMethod = "POST";
        const results = await data.callApi.callApiJson({
            apiMethod: apiMethod,
            httpMethod: httpMethod,
            req: req
        });
```

For case 2 there are multiple ways to store the necessary instance data in the browser (or use query parameters) so that when the application is restarted, it has the necessary context.

Answer (score 0):

I had to face this situation when I was implementing DocuSign-related developments.
solution was,

1. need to create a new widget in your angular application
2. this route (your created widget route) needs to be set as return-url in your .net application.
3. when triggered after your work in the iframe call the new widget you created.

> So you can handle iframe close functionality using sessionStorage.

---

```
    export class CloseDocusignComponent implements OnInit {

         constructor() { }

         ngOnInit(): void {
         sessionStorage.setItem('closeModal', 'true')
      }
```

}

---

```
            var client = new HttpClient();
            string url = Session.BasePath + "/restapi/v2.1/accounts/" + Session.AccountId + "/envelopes/" + envelopId + "/views/correct";

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");  var content = new StringContent("{\n  \"beginOnTagger\": \"true\",\n  \"showEditPages\": \"false\",\n  \"returnUrl\": \"here-is-your-baseurl/docusign-close\",\n  \"suppressNavigation\": \"true\" \n\n}", null, "application/json");
            request.Content = content;

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            // Parse JSON
            JObject data = JObject.Parse(responseJson);
            // Access the URL
            string urlResponse = data["url"].ToString();
            return urlResponse.ToString();
```